# Is it possible to mount Vue.js components on the DOM in production using Rails, Webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack

I have a Rails 5.2.1 app and would like to integrate Vue in a piecemeal fashion;  I have everything working nicely in development with Foreman starting Rails and the webpacker dev server together.

I wrapped everything inside the body tag in a div with id="vue-app", and mount the app using the following in packs/app.js:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const app = new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ i18n }, App)).$mount('#vue-app')
})
```

This works fine in development - I can add vue directives on any element and drop in my components wherever I need to. However, when running the same thing in production mode (after asset precompilation), the app fails to mount to #vue-app and just replaces it with an HTML comment.  Vue itself is loading fine, compilation appears to be fine, everything is being found - it just silently fails to mount.

I've been researching for a couple of hours, and can't find anything besides duplicates of this: [Vue.js app works in development but not mounting template in production with Rails 5.2.0 / Webpacker - blank screen with no errors in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957238/vue-js-app-works-in-development-but-not-mounting-template-in-production-with-rai?rq=1)

His solution was to change the mounting to a render function on a new element, but ends with 'I still don't know how to use DOM as template with Vue in production though.'

It severely diminishes the appeal of Vue if it can't be mounted on existing elements, so I'm curious if it is at all possible to use a DOM template in production with Rails/webpacker?

Comment: Are you using string or DOM templates (`template: '<div>foo</div>'`) at all? The Vue template compiler may not be included in the production build. If you're using precompiled .vue  files with [vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/) then you should be good.

Comment: Yes, I wrapped everything inside the body tags in a div with id="vue-app" (sorry, just noticed the tags were stripped out of the original question, I'll update that now)

Comment: The way I do it is I file.read the html from dist/ and have it link to the JS and CSS files from public/dist.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved my own problem - I believe it was caused by a mismatch between dependencies in package.json.  I may have inadvertently messed it up while I was working on other aspects of the Vue app.  I generated a new Rails application, added Webpacker and Vue, confirmed it worked with DOM templates in production with compiled assets, and then copied the versions out of that clean package.json into my existing app.